# Selenium element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, html, list, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this particular site with Python: https://www.milanofinanza.it/quotazioni/ricerca/listino-completo-2ae?refresh_cens.

I need to get all the isin codes and the names. My idea was to get them all in 2 separated lists, to do that I try to get the entire column (by changing the Xpath to tr rather than tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERti6.png)) and then add it to the list.

My code goes through the pages but at a certain point just stop working (even if I add `time.sleep(10)` to be sure that the code starts scraping when the site is fully loaded).

My code looks like this:

```
wd = wd.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(10)

wd.get('https://www.milanofinanza.it/quotazioni/ricerca/listino-completo-2ae')

company_name = []
isin = []
for n in range(0,15):
time.sleep(10)
tickers = wd.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mainbox']/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
isin = wd.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/span")
for el in tickers:
    company_name.append(el.text)
for i in isin:
    isin.append(i.text)

l=wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/button[4]")
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",l)
print("data collected")
```

How can I solve this problem? Here some pictures to better understand:

Name:

[image]

Isin:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I can't see how your existing code is working.
On my side I see the locator you are using for `isin` matching nothing.
I have updated locators here.
I would advice you never using automatically created locators.
Also the code you presenting here is missing indentations. I hope your actual code having proper indentations.
Please see if this will work better:

```py
wd = wd.Chrome()

wd.get('https://www.milanofinanza.it/quotazioni/ricerca/listino-completo-2ae')

company_name = []
isin = []
for n in range(0,15):
    time.sleep(10)
    tickers = wd.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[contains(@class,'celled')]//tbody//tr//td[1]")
    isins = wd.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[contains(@class,'celled')]//tbody//tr//td[10]")
    for el in tickers:
        company_name.append(el.text)
    for is_el in isins:
        isin.append(is_el.text)
 
    l=wd.find_element(By.XPATH,'//nav//button[@ng-click="getDataTableNextClick()"]')
    wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",l)
```

Comment: i tried and got this error from isin.append(i.text):  'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Try renaming the variables there as I did now. Please let me know if that helped. I can't see another objects names `i` in the code you share but maybe you are not sharing all your actual code?

Comment: I see, you defined the list for texts `isin = []` and the list of web elements with the same name... `for i in isin:`

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to tell you that selenium is probably a little bloated for what you're doing. There are times when you need a full-fledged browser, but this isn't one of them. I'd recommend requests and beautiful soup (it's more suited to making a shit load of requests.) I appreciate that you were running javascript to get more items (although for me, the reloading button wasn't doing anything) In that case, it is necessary. But, I source viewed the website to discover that the data you want can be retrieved in JSON format (so no need for BS) and in a simple get request.

```
import requests

data = requests.get("https://www.milanofinanza.it/Mercati/GetDataTabelle?alias=&campoOrdinamento=0002&numElem=30&ordinamento=asc&page=4&url=listino-completo-2ae?refresh_cens")
print(data.text)
```

Or do it like this so it's easier to adjust the params:

```
def pack(**kwargs):
    return kwargs
data2 = requests.get("https://www.milanofinanza.it/Mercati/GetDataTabelle", params=pack(alias="",campoOrdinamento="0002",numElem=30,ordinamento="asc",page=4,url="listino-completo-2ae",refresh_cens=""))
```

I'm out of time; if I got the wrong data, LMK, and I'll correct the answer.